# How can I get all configuration properties for an Active profile in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I get all configuration properties for an Active profile in Spring Boot? I'm not interested in getting individual properties which you can get with *@Value* or *@ConfigurationProperties* component. I'd like to get all available properties. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Founded here https://gist.github.com/sandor-nemeth/f6d2899b714e017266cb9cce66bc719d

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.EnumerablePropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PropertyLogger  {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertyLogger.class);

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        final Environment env = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        LOGGER.info("====== Environment and configuration ======");
        LOGGER.info("Active profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
        final MutablePropertySources sources = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources();
        StreamSupport.stream(sources.spliterator(), false)
                .filter(ps -> ps instanceof EnumerablePropertySource)
                .map(ps -> ((EnumerablePropertySource) ps).getPropertyNames())
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .distinct()
                .filter(prop -> !(prop.contains("credentials") || prop.contains("password")))
                .forEach(prop -> LOGGER.info("{}: {}", prop, env.getProperty(prop)));
        LOGGER.info("===========================================");
    }
}
```